# Regex Vs Char functions to handle user inputs. What is best and why?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a task to validate user inputs in winforms c# app. in their user should prevent from entering special characters.

I have found two methods do it.

```
  var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
            if (regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

second one is

```
e.Handled = Char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar)
```

and there are other validation for this Char class.

What is the best way? Is using Regex is good? Are these two methods are equal? Is Char functions use Regex operations behind the scene?

Comment: Without a metric for objectively reaching an answer, questions asking which way is "best" aren't really on-topic for this website.

Comment: Also note that your two methods aren't equivalent. [Example](https://rextester.com/UULE53191).

Comment: Perhaps validating at submit or focus out will be better than on every key stroke. Then you won't have to care about nano second performance disparency.

Comment: As Jon mentioned, it´s hard to determine what is "better" when they produce different results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether or not a character `IsPunctuation`, use the Char function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.ispunctuation?view=netcore-3.1

> Indicates whether a **Unicode** character is categorized as a punctuation mark.

Unicode being the important part here. While your regex handles the Latin alphabet, it will reply as punctuation for any other letter of any other alphabet.

More false positives and false negatives could come up from using a custom regex.

Comment: So you recommend Char.IsPunctuation handles this better than Regex?

Comment: Absolutely! The correct functionality is much more difficult to implement with Regex, so go with the built in version.